# Need help on updating a data on a database table using facebox

Tags: php, facebox

Good day to all of you. As the title says I need help about facebox when updating a data(s).

Here's the code for the button to show the facebox

```
echo '
        td>
            <a  rel="facebox" href="../admin/c_status.php?id='.$row["userID"].'">Edit</a>
        </td>
    ';
```

and here's the code inside facebox

```
 <?php
include("../db/dbCon.php");
//$id = $_GET['id'];
//echo $id;
?>

Status
<form method="post">
    <select name="selActive" id ="selActive">
        <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
        <option value="IN-ACTIVE">IN-ACTIVE</option>
        <option value="GRADUATE">GRADUATE</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-large" name="saveChangeButton" id ="saveChangeButton">Save Changes</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['saveChangeButton'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $status = $_POST['selActive'];

        $cStatus = $conn->prepare("UPDATE useraccount SET status = :status WHERE userID = :userID");
        $cStatus->bindParam(':status', $status);
        $cStatus->bindParam(':userID', $id);
        $cStatus->execute();
    }
?>
```

The problem I encounter is the data won't update via clicking the edit button BUT when I edit via address bar like "http://localhost/ict/admin/c_status.php". It will work.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an input type hidden and just make its value equal to `$_GET['id']`

```
   <form method="post">
        <select name="selActive" id ="selActive">
            <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
            <option value="IN-ACTIVE">IN-ACTIVE</option>
            <option value="GRADUATE">GRADUATE</option>
        </select>

        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
        <br>
        <br>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-large" name="saveChangeButton" id ="saveChangeButton">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
```

then transfer you php code to update useraccount below or above your link.When you used facebox, the form you have opened as pop up became part of this file therefore it is logical to transfer your php code to update accounts here since you didn't specify the action attribute of the form above.

```
   echo '<td>
            <a  rel="facebox" href="../admin/c_status.php?id='.$row["userID"].'">Edit</a>
        </td>';
    include("../db/dbCon.php");
    if(isset($_POST['saveChangeButton'])){
        $id = $_POST['userid'];
        $status = $_POST['selActive'];

        $cStatus = $conn->prepare("UPDATE useraccount SET status = :status WHERE userID = :userID");
        $cStatus->bindParam(':status', $status);
        $cStatus->bindParam(':userID', $id);
        $cStatus->execute();
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the reply! I edit my post... I correct the code about <a href> it's inside the php code. I copy the code and apply to mine but it's not working.

Comment: is there any other way? because no need to open a new page just to edit the status, instead a box will pop-up.

Comment: I didn't notice you edit your post... Now it's working... All I need is put a code that will refresh the page after the process is done.... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer since it helps you :)

Comment: how? I'm sorry... I'm still newbie here in stackoverflow... I just click the arrow button that facing upward... is that enough? :)

Comment: btw can you explain how you fix it? because that code is from my classmate... the "isset($_POST['saveChangeButton'])" is in the c_status.php but you move that in the page where is the edit button.

Comment: when you used facebox the php file c_status.php became part of the php file where your link resides. Almost the same as include or require in php